# Assign different colors to polydata in paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview

Trying to avoid defining multiple individual polygons/quad, so I use polydata.
I need to define multiple polydata in a Matlab generated vtk file, but each one should be assigned a different color (defined in a lookup table).
The following code gives an error and accepts only the first color which it assigns to all polydata.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 5.1
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 12 float 
0.500000 1.000000 0.000000
0.353553 1.000000 -0.353553
0.000000 1.000000 -0.500000
-0.353553 1.000000 -0.353553
-0.500000 1.000000 0.000000
-0.353553 1.000000 0.353553
0.000000 1.000000 0.500000
0.353553 1.000000 0.353553
0. 0. 0.
1. 1. 1.
2. 2. 2.
1. 2. 1.
POLYGONS 3 12
OFFSETS vtktypeint64
0 8 12 
CONNECTIVITY vtktypeint64
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
9 10 11 12
CELL_DATA 2
SCALARS SMEARED float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE victor
0 1
LOOKUP_TABLE victor 1
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
```

[image: Generated image]

Answer (score 0):

> `LOOKUP_TABLE victor 1`

This should be `LOOKUP_TABLE victor 2`, as you define 2 RGBA points in your table